# Facebook comments box: Possibility to really set num_posts = 0?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, seo, comments

I'm using the comments box on my site to get more users socially involved and at the same time I'm reading the Graph API to print those comments on the same site to make it crawlable for search engines. Problem is now that for a real user the comments show up twice (through my graph api print AND through the actual fb:comments plugin box). 
Any ideas how I could solve this ?

Would prefer to show only the comment-field from FB and use my own echo to show the comments as this way enables it to REALLY moderate the comments (not just set it to limited visibility). Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some sort of solution for my problem. It's not perfect, but the closest one can get to what I wanted:

- Instead of directly returning the query from the Graph API, I attached a script to the `comment.create` event. This script writes the new comment into my database, where I can moderate again. This way I have to double-moderate, but therefore I don't have any unwanted comments on my site.
- I also found out that with the old **deprecated** comment-box you can set the comments that get natively shown by facebook to 0. That way only the already moderated comments get shown by my own script coupled with my database. It works the way I want it, even for friends of the unwanted commenter.

Hope that helps someone else too!